# Search in a sorted array of ints which rolls over

Tags: algorithm, search, performance

Is there a easy way to search in an array like this? Some examples below :

```
5 6 7 8 19 45 21 32 40  // Rolled over at 7 th element
15 22 32 45 121 341 40  // Rolled over at 7 th element
1 22 32 45 121 341 400  // Rolled over at 0 th element
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to find?

Comment: @Nikita I want to find a cucumber!

Comment: @javaguy What's rollover? You mean, array is split in two parts, each strictly ascending? Can there be more than two parts?

Comment: I guess it's about finding the position where the number becomes smaller than the previous one. In that case, it could be solved by saving the most recent number and comparing it against the next one.

Comment: @Nikita let's assume only 1 rollover point.

Comment: `5 4 3 2 1` // Rolled over at the 0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th element.

Comment: And are we searching to find the rollover point, or are we searching for an element within it?  Are you confirming Nikita's answer that it's in two sections, each strictly ascending?  Can you edit the question to make it more clear please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any algorithm to find "rollover" point would have at least O(n) complexity in worst case.

Imagine, you have sorted array and checked less than n of its elements. For example, if in array `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` you didn't check element `4`, I can replace it with `100` and create "rollover" (`1 2 3 100 5 6 7 8 9 10`). Your algorithm won't know, since it never read this element.

Thus, your only option is to go through all elements until you find rollover.

Thanks to **Eyal Schneider** for a useful comment.

BTW, am I the only one here who doesn't understand etymology of the word "rollover"?

Comment: I think your proof can be made simpler: We know that for every searched number x and sequence S there exist a positions p(S,x) which isn't inspected at all. Define S=1,2,3,..,N, x=2*N. Now build a legal S' by replacing position p(S,x) with 2*N. The algorithm must fail for S or S'.

Comment: @Eyal Good idea, thanks. (and you don't really need _x_ if you search for "rollover")

Comment: By the way, a slightly different version of the question HAS a logarithmic solution; This happens when the rollover point marks the start/end point of a sorted circular array (e.g. 5,7,10,1,4 but not 5,7,10,8,20)

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to do many searches, you could do one pre-processing pass, using linear search, to get the indices of all the rollover places, then do binary search within each section.

But if you're going to search just once I think you have to do linear search.  So either way there's a linear search involved.

If you go with the "find rollover first" technique, and you know there's only one rollover point, you can at least bail out of that linear search as soon as you find the point.

Comment: linear search will be slow! How do I find the rollover point quickly?

Comment: Sorry, can't think of a way to avoid at least one linear search.

Answer (score 2):

this should help http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=1068

Answer (score 0):

Think of your array as a mathematical function, what you want is the local maxima of your function. Although I don't have enough knowledge to explain, you might want to do some research about [Hill Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). Using some heuristics, you might be able to find your local maxima more efficiently.